# Can't save newly created files, or close them or TeXShop once they are opened

Tags: mac, texshop

Since a few days ago, on macOS Venture 13.2.1, if I open TeXShop and create a new file, I can't save it, whether I use cmd+s or the save option under File->Save. I can't rename or close the untitled file either, or close TeXShop. The only way I can close them is to force quit them, and when I re-open it, the unsaved files open as well. I need to go into Library-> Autosave Information and delete them from there to avoid it. I can still edit and save my existing files, and TeXShop closes fine if they are the only ones open.

Comment: Welcome. What is your TeXShop version? If recall correctly I had a similar bug few weeks ago, and after updating the app, it was gone.

Comment: Ah yes, I thought I was up to date, this has sorted it. Question, when updating, did you also get the dialog AutoUpdate wants to make changes? It's been a while since I've had to install this on a new system. Can't remember if that is part of the Sparkle update framework.

Comment: Yes, just updated from version 5.10 to 5.12, and I have the Autoupdate dialog. Seems legit.

Comment: Really appreciate the help @quark67 :)

Comment: Do you want to write an answer so I can mark it as accepted so you'll get the points XD

Comment: Do you recall from which version you made the update? You can find the information by entering in Apple's Time Machine if you use this backup system. Go in Finder, display the TeXhop app in column mode (which displays the version number), then use Time machine to go to a date before your update. Then click on cancel to going out of Time Machine. I'm curious if you had the same old version.

Comment: My version was one from 2020. I never updated as I have never had an issue before, and was using overleaf for some of my work.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem after upgrading to Ventura 13.2.1 with an old version of TexShop. I couldn't compile or close a new file.  @quark67's solution worked. Worth making an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to a more recent version of TexShop like quark67 suggested solved my issue.